# Modern reference request concerning Efimov's "On dyadic spaces"

Tags: reference-request, gn.general-topology

Is there any modern reference (book, textbook, monograph, etc.) that contains the following result of B. Efimov (On dyadic spaces // Dokl. Akad. Nauk SSSR 151 (1963) (Russian). English translation: Soviet Math. Dokl. 4 (1963), 1131-1134.):

Every non-isolated point of a dyadic space is the limit of a sequence of distinct points.

I don't have access to the article. Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you provide us the definition of dyadic space? I'm curious about it. 

On the other hand, about the reference that you mention, maybe it is worth to get the original paper. I'm not sure but I think that I can get it from the library and scan it. Let me know if you would like me to do that.

Comment: A space $X$ is called dyadic if it is a continuous image of the space $\{0,1\}^I$ for some set $I$. Compact metric spaces and compact topological groups are among dyadic spaces. I would really appreciate if you can scan the paper for me.

Comment: Do you mean "is the limit of a **convergent** sequence"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the paper: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/94324934/Maths/efimov.pdf/

I hope that it works.

Comment: No worries. I hope it will be helpful